# Batch file to copy files based on file name to multiple folders

Tags: batch-file

Ok super new to this but I am needing some help.  My situation is that I have multiple pdf files in multiple folders.  Example:

Folder - "Drawings for XYZ"

Contains Files - "Drawing - 10", "Drawing - 11", "Drawing - 12"

I would like to copy each file in the folder to another location.  Each file will be moved individually to it's own folder, so for example:

Folder - "10"

Contains File - "Drawing - 10"

Folder - "11"

Contains File - "Drawing - 11"

Folder - "12"

Contains File - "Drawing - 12"

All of the target folders are already created so I know the path for each folder of where I would like each file to go, but doing this manually for over 1000 files does not seem the way to go.  Will someone please help me out?

Comment: how exactly the files are named? Are all the file names has the same pattern?

Comment: yes the files are titled in identical manner.  xxxxx.xxx - IFC.pdf       each "x" in the file name represents a number for example 50832.001 - IFC.     All files are located in one folder.  I can place the target folders in the same main folder the files are in or place them any where they need to be.

Answer (score 0):

If your files are named exactly like this (Something - number.pdf) AND they are located in the same folder as your bat file AND the folders 1, 2, 3... are also located in the same folder, this code schould work:

```
FOR %%a IN (*.pdf) DO (
    FOR /F "tokens=3" %%b IN ("%%a") DO (
        FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=." %%c IN ("%%b") DO (
            COPY "%%~a" "%%~dpa%%c\%%~nxa" /Y
        )
    )
)
```

If the pathes differ, you will have to make some adjustments.